# Set current_user in Controller Test with Rails 5 Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, minitest, paper-trail-gem

Anyone know how to set the devise helper function #current_user in a controller test (using fixture data) for a Rails 5 app? I've tried the following:

- `sign_in users(:example_user)`
- `@current_user = users(:example_user)`
- `current_user = users(:example_user)`
- `@controller.stubs(:current_user).returns(users(:example_user))`.

I'm writing tests for the [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem, which uses #current_user to set the 'whodunnit' attribute (i.e. id of current_user) on the version.

Comment: Don't use controller tests for a new app as [they are depreciated](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html). Instead use `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` as this is a more future proof way forward. An added bonus is you can simply use `include Warden::Test::Helpers` and login users with `login_as @user`

Comment: I missed the part about writing it for the paper_trail gem. But my advice still stands. Convert it to an `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` and stop poking around in the internals.

Comment: Max, I think your comment could be an answer. I use `login_as` on my paper_trail projects. To the OP: re: paper_trail, make sure to read section [4.a. Finding Out Who Was Responsible For A Change](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#4a-finding-out-who-was-responsible-for-a-change)